# Can install and run MATLAB Distributed Computing Server on a Desktop version of linux?

Tags: linux, matlab, parallel-processing, cluster-computing

I installed MATLAB Distributed Computing Server on a Desktop version of linux (Mint) but when i run the command ./lmstart to start the licence manager it does not start. It also does not fill the log file and log file is empty.

The licence is a server licence. The version of MATLAB is 2012a

Comment: In theory there should not be any problem... And most likely this post on the matlab forum answers your question (mint is a debian derivative) : [http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/97361-why-am-i-unable-to-start-the-flexnet-license-manager-v11-8-or-higher-on-debian-based-linux-distribut]

Comment: It worked. You are fantastic my friend.